# Add a value to dropdown in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown like this

```
<select id="valueImportMatchs">
    <option id="5" value="id|image|name|reference|category|price_tex|price_tin|condition|no">test23</option>
    <option id="6" value="id|image|name|reference|category|price_tex|price_tin|condition|no">test235</option>
    <option id="7" value="id|image|supplier|reference|category|price_tex|price_tin|condition|no">t</option>
</select>
```

So i tried to work with ChoiceType form field type
I successfully generated the listbox with option id, and choice label but never for the option values

This is my formType code

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $idSite = $this->session->get('_defaultWebSite')->getId();
    $em = $this->em;
    $data = array();
    $importsMach = $em->getRepository('ImportCsvBundle:ImportMatch')->findBy(array('idSite' => (int) $idSite));
    if(count($importsMach))
        foreach ($importsMach as $key => $importMatch)
            $data[$importMatch->getMatching()] = $importMatch;

        $builder
        ->add('nameList', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $data,
            'choice_label' => function($importMatch, $key, $index) {
                /** @var Category $category */
                return strtoupper($importMatch->getName());
            },
            'choice_attr' => function($importMatch, $key, $index) {
                return ['id' => strtolower($importMatch->getId())];
            },
            'choice_value' => function($importMatch) {

                return  $importMatch->getMatching();
            },        

             'choices_as_values' => true,        

        ]);
}
```

And this is my entity ImportMatch.php content

```
class ImportMatch
```

{

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this::$nameList[] = $this;
}
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_site", type="integer")
 */
private $idSite;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="matching", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $matching;

 /**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name_list", type="array")
 */

private static $nameList;
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set idSite
 *
 * @param integer $idSite
 *
 * @return ImportMatch
 */
public function setIdSite($idSite)
{
    $this->idSite = $idSite;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idSite
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getIdSite()
{
    return $this->idSite;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return ImportMatch
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set matching
 *
 * @param string $matching
 *
 * @return ImportMatch
 */
public function setMatching($matching)
{
    $this->matching = $matching;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get matching
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMatching()
{
    return $this->matching;
}

/**
 * Set nameList
 *
 * @param array $nameList
 *
 * @return ImportMatch
 */
public function setNameList($nameList)
{
    $this::$nameList = $nameList;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nameList
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getNameList()
{
    return $this::$nameList;
}
```

}

Edit: i got this error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getMatching" of class "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection".
```

On this line

```
   return  $importMatch->getMatching();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly braces `{ }` after your `if` (!!!):
it should be:

```
if(count($importsMach)) {
    foreach ($importsMach as $key => $importMatch)
        ...
    ]);
}
```

EDIT: thanks tarek, i updated my answer

Comment: foreach has one child, braces are not required

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using query builder

```
 ->add('nameList', EntityType::class, [

             'class'=>'ImportCsvBundle:ImportMatch',   
            'choice_label' => function($importMatch, $key, $index) {

                return strtoupper($importMatch->getName());
            },
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('im')

                        ->where('im.idSite = :idSite')
                        ->orderBy('im.id', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('idSite', $this->session->get('_defaultWebSite')->getId());
            },    
            'choice_attr' => function($importMatch, $key, $index) {
                return ['id' => strtolower($importMatch->getId())];
            },
            'choice_value' => function($importMatch) {
                return $importMatch->getMatching();
            },   


             'choices_as_values' => false,        

        ])
```